# Regex Remove unnecessary symbols with certain rules c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, expression

I want to remove all unnecessary characters so the name can be valid, here are the rules :

•   Has length between 3 and 16 characters
•   Contains only letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores
•   Has no redundant symbols before, after or in between

This is the input:

**Jeff, john45, ab, cd, peter-ivanov, @smith, sh, too_long_username, !lleg@l ch@rs, jeffbutt**

My Regex so far is : https://regexr.com/4ahls, and I want to remove:
@smith
!lleg@l
ch@rs

Comment: And what problem do you have? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Try it like this: `string.Join(", ", Regex.Matches(s, @"(?<!\S)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}(?![^\s,])").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value))`

Answer (score 1):

Your own regex `\b([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){3,16}\b` is good enough for giving the intended match but `\b` fails to do their job and will allow matching partially in a word like `@smith` to give you `smith` because `@` is not part of word character and hence `s` in `smith` will match as the point in between `@` and `s` is indeed a word boundary. You will need a different regex ensuring the word is preceded/followed by a space and in addition comma too as some words are followed by comma and you want to count them in. Try using this regex,

```
(?<= |^)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{3,16}(?=[ ,]|$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lVYTt7/1)**

This should give you matches to only words that follow your rules.

Note: Always keep `-` either at very start or very end while having it in a character set, otherwise it sometimes behaves weird and gives unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern: `(?=^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{3,16}$).+`

Generally positive lookaheads `(?=...)` are used to assert that some rules are valid, as you want to do. Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of a string

`[a-zA-Z0-9-_]{3,16}` - match at least 3 and 16 at most of characters in a character class: `a-zA-Z` - all letters, `0-9` - digits, `-_` - hyphen or underscore

`$` - end of a string

And if this assertion is successfull, then match everything with `.*`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/q3NFdw/2)

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need a regex to solve this. Use old good `string.Split()` and process names

```
var input = "Jeff, john45, ab, cd, peter-ivanov, @smith, sh, too_long_username, !lleg@l ch@rs, jeffbutt";
var listOfNames = input.Split(new[] {",", " "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(l => l.Length >= 3 && l.Length <= 18) // filter by length
    .Where(l => l.All(c => char.IsDigit(c) || char.IsLetter(c) || c == '-')) // filter by spec chars
    .ToList();
```

now you have a list of four names. If you want to turn it back to string just join your names:

```
var singleLine = string.Join(", ", listOfNames);
// singleLine is "Jeff, john45, peter-ivanov, jeffbutt"
```

Comment: The names are dynamic, it can be different names, just for the example I have posted them.
The issue shoud be resolved with regex.

Comment: @NikoKaradzhov you can modify `input` in my example. My solution will work well with other names until it separated with comas. _shoud be resolved with regex_  why? Is this homework or interview task? If not I don't see a reasons to bound a solution to regex

Comment: because the task is to solve it with regex, I should also train regex for the upcoming exam :D